# Is it possible to run iis6 and iis7 in parallel?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis-7, iis-6

We have a huge amount of webApplications running on IIS6. Because we want to run an MS MVC2 or MVC3 Webapp we have to use IIS7. Migrating these huge amount of IIS6 webapps is way to time intensive for us.

is it possible to run IIS6 and IIS7 on one machine?

Thanks!

Comment: "Because we want to run an MS MVC2..."  MVC is compatible with IIS6 and 7. So I'm not sure what you mean by this.

Comment: I heard that IIS6 has a lot of problems with MVC2. That is the reason why i think about IIS7.

Comment: Haacked has a blog that will help you with IIS6 setup issues http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/26/asp.net-mvc-on-iis-6-walkthrough.aspx  I've gone through this myself and it wasn't too bad.  Just read the blog carefully.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No - it isn't possible to run IIS6 and IIS7 on the same machine.

The version of IIS for a machine is dictated by the operating system and cannot be installed standalone.

For instance, Windows XP shipped with IIS5.1, Windows 2003 shipped with IIS 6.0, Windows 2008 shipped with IIS7.0 and Windows 2008 R2 shipped with IIS7.5.

Comment: Just to clarify, this is not quite true. It is possible to run IIS7.5 for web applications and IIS6 for SMTP services etc. on the same Windows 2008 R2 machine.

Answer (score 1):

You can use IIS 7 / 7.5 but just run the application pools in the **"classic" pipeline mode**, which is the same as running your application in IIS6.

That way you can handle legacy applications and still be free to leverage the advantages of IIS7.  Here's an article on the pipeline differences.

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/243/aspnet-integration-with-iis-7/

Comment: Running apps in IIS7/7.5 under "classic" mode is more similar to IIS6, but it really isn't the same. There are plenty of other differences between the two.

Answer (score 0):

If you want them all to answer on port 80 you will have to setup some type of proxy to route calls to the correct IIS. Say you let one of them (perhaps IIS) run on port 80, then you need to setup IIS7 to run on another port and intercept calls to the IIS7-app and rewrite them to use another port.

Have you tried running your existing applications in IIS7? They might work?

Comment: Thank you for the idea. I havn't tried to run the current apps in IIS7, but the IT does not want this :(

Comment: you can't run different versions of IIS on the same machine.

Answer (score 0):

no it is not possible . why because, just consider an mobile app and if update came means it will replace the older one like same it will get work.
if you need to check both in the sense , just install other version in virtual machine and we can easily see the difference between both